# What does 'login-page="/login.jsp" login-processing-url="/login.do"' mean in Spring OAuth2 tonr?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I am working a Oauth 2 implementation project, below is what I found in the configuration file from Spring Oauth2 tonr sample project:

---

```
<http access-denied-page="/login.jsp?authorization_error=true" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
    <intercept-url pattern="/sparklr/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/facebook/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />

    <form-login authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?authentication_error=true" default-target-url="/index.jsp"
        **login-page="/login.jsp"** **login-processing-url="/login.do"** />
    <logout logout-success-url="/index.jsp" logout-url="/logout.do" />
    <anonymous />
    <custom-filter ref="oauth2ClientFilter" after="EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER" />
</http>
```

---

My questions are:

1. How "login-processing-url="/login.do"" get mapped? I don't see corresponding mappings in tonr
2. What is the use of oauth2ClientFilter?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**1. login-processing-url**

The config you quoted configures Spring (internally) to listen for requests to that URL.  Since the web.xml defines something like the following servlet and mapping then Spring's dispatcher service will receive the request and can process accordingly:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You're free to set it to another Url, just make sure your "action" attribute of your login form matches it.

**2. oauth2ClientFilter**

This sets up the client context so that Tonr is able to make requests to Sparklr on behalf of the authorized client.